# Cannot execute pendingIntent in App Widget (Android12)

Tags: android, android-studio, android-pendingintent, android-appwidget, android-12

My widget is working and directly going to the activity I put below. But when it comes to my Android 12, when I click my widget on the home screen it only runs the default starting activity that can see from the android manifest. How can I fix this? TIA

```
@Override
    public void onUpdate(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager, int[] appWidgetIds) {
        // There may be multiple widgets active, so update all of them

        for (int appWidgetId : appWidgetIds) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(context, SecondPage.class);
            PendingIntent pendingIntent;

            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
                pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context,
                        0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT | PendingIntent.FLAG_IMMUTABLE);

            }else {
                pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context,
                        0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

            }

            RemoteViews views = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.thisWidget);
            views.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.thisBtn, pendingIntent);

            appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(appWidgetId, views);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's all good now. I just reset the data of the application from my android phone. I'm sorry though I had no option left because I was finding the problem for hours.